# Setting KDE Task switcher to list windows from all screens in Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, kde, kubuntu, kde-4

*I moved this question from Unix/Linux SE, since I think it fits here best.*

When I alt-tab in Kubuntu 12.04, the listed windows are from the current screen only. In the Task Switcher settings, the "List windows" option is set to "All desktops", a setting which I changed a couple of times just in case it gets fixed, but with no luck.

It used to list all windows in the past. Since then:

- I changed the effect options (listed in Task Switcher) a month or two ago
- I applied several updates (system-wide, as in `apt-get update/dist-upgrade` )

but I cannot say for certain when the problem first occured.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that disabling "Separate screen focus" in KDE's Window Behavior solves the problem.